# Changing the icon of selected tab

Tags: android, android-tablayout

Im setting the tablayout as follows,

```
 private void setupTabIcons() {

        TextView tabOne = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        tabOne.setText("Status");
        tabOne.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.status, 0, 0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne);

        TextView tabTwo = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        tabTwo.setText("Rating");
        tabTwo.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.rateit, 0, 0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(tabTwo);
}
```

How can I be able to change the icon of selected tab? im using tablayout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am using `TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener`:

```
wptabs.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            tab.setIcon(R.drawable.newicon);
             //also you can use tab.setCustomView() too
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            tab.setIcon(R.drawable.oldicon);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: How to get the index of tab. I have four tabs in total

Comment: tab.getPosition() will return you tabs position. For example if you get first tab position=0 and fourth tab position =3