# Java android tab

Tags: java, android, tabs

How to change a icon in selected tab? I do this for set icons in tab :

```
   private void createTabIcons() {
        TextView tabOne = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        tabOne.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, R.drawable.start_n, 0, 0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne);
    }
```

But when I select or scroll tab I want to change a icon in selected tab and change to default icon in previesl tab

Comment: Change the icon on OntabChangeListener

Comment: @TerrilThomas but how I can chenge icons ?

Comment: private void createTabIcons(int image) {
        TextView tabOne = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        tabOne.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, image, 0, 0);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne);
    }

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37630765/changing-the-icon-of-selected-tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using material design then try this

```
       private int[] imageResIdcolor = {
                                    R.drawable.ic_dashboard,
                                    R.drawable.ic_chats,
                                    R.drawable.ic_friends,
                                    R.drawable.ic_contacts,
                            };

        private int[] imageResId = {
                            R.drawable.ic_dashbordblue,
                            R.drawable.ic_chatsblue,
                            R.drawable.ic_friendsblue,
                            R.drawable.ic_contactsblue,
                    };

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

   tabLayout.getTabAt(tab.getPosition()).setIcon(imageResId[tab.getPosition()]);
              }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
         tabLayout.getTabAt(tab.getPosition()).setIcon(imageResIdcolor[tab.getPosition()]);
             }
```